# Reload a React Native class component

Tags: react-native

I have a class component **directions** in my project. I navigate to another component from it using `this.props.navigation.navigate()`. Now the problem is that I want to navigate back to the same directions component but with passing new values, ie I want it to reload from scratch, defining state variables once again. How can I do it?

Using navigation.navigate() simply takes me back to the previous state the screen has been.

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('direction',{

            riderLocation:this.state.rideInfo.location,
            ride_id:this.state.ride_id,
            
          });
```

And this is the componentDidMount of directions.

```
componentDidMount(){

  alert('componentDidMount');
   const {navigation,route}=this.props;
        this.state.riderLocation = navigation.getParam('riderLocation');
        this.state.ride_id= navigation.getParam('ride_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "directions" component, use "componentDidMount" method.

Inside "componentDidMount" method, call a function which updates the state value as desired.

Once you are redirected back to the "directions" component, then "componentDidMount" will run and the state will be updated.

====
Edit:
Try using componentDidUpdate() method in "directions" component.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.navigation.getParam('ride_id') !== this.props.navigation.getParam('ride_id')) {
    const {
      navigation,
      route
    } = this.props;
    this.setState({
      riderLocation: navigation.getParam('riderLocation'),
      ride_id: navigation.getParam('ride_id')
    })
  }
}
```

Also instead of "this.state.riderLocation" and "this.state.ride_id" use this.setState in componentDidMount(), just like I have written in componentDidUpdate().

Comment: componentDidMount is only running the first time screen is loaded, not when I redirect to it.

Comment: Oh.. Could you please update your question by adding code snippets?

Comment: Ofcourse, but I'm not sure what to show you though, if you want to see something else, please let me know